# Imported class cannot be used as service in Angular.js with TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack

I'm converting an ES6 project to TypeScript and I've encountered an issue when using `@typed/angular` with the `.service` call in Angular.js.

If I do this:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
class OrderTreeService {}

export const orderTree = angular
    .module('orderTree', [])
    .service('OrderTreeService', OrderTreeService)
    .name;
```

It works perfectly.
However, if I move that service to a file `order-service.service.ts` and do this:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import { OrderTreeService } from './order-tree.service';

export const orderTree = angular
    .module('orderTree', [])
    .service('OrderTreeService', OrderTreeService)
    .name;
```

Then it no longer worked and has this error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof OrderTreeService' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Injectable<Function>'.
  Type 'typeof OrderTreeService' is not assignable to type '(string | Function)[]'.
    Property 'pop' is missing in type 'typeof OrderTreeService'.
```

I can't figure out what the difference is? Is it losing some type information somewhere along the way?

This is the contents of `order-service.service.ts`:

```
export class OrderTreeService {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure, but while moving `OrderTreeService` to single file, did you export the `OrderTreeService` service from `order-tree.service.ts`?

**order-tree.service.ts**

```
export class OrderTreeService {}
```